# How to click a specific button every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeat, clicking

The webpage's code is as follows :

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        Slots
        <p>The current jackpot is 23220!<p/>
        <p>You lose.</p>
        <form method=post action=/games/slots.php>
            <input type=hidden name='hash_sub' value='MjEzOA=='>
            <input type=hidden name='act' value='spin'>
            <input type=submit value='Spin again!'>
        </form>
        <a href='slots.php'>Go Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code :

```
setInterval(function solo() {
    jQuery('content').children('submit[value="Spin again!"]').click();
}, 1000);
```

I am not sure what I am missing, the page loads but the button is not clicked at all. There are no console log errors.

Comment: Use jQuery('#content') see http://jsfiddle.net/8zj4ez7w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `#` with ID and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/). As `.children()` only traverses immediate children where as `.find()` will look into descendants.

Use

```
setInterval(function () {
    jQuery('#content').find('input[type=submit][value="Spin again!"]').click();
}, 1000);
```

Also when you use `children('submit[value="Spin again!"]')` it looks for `submit` element with value `Spin again!`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Lwqn7xf5/)

Comment: For some reason this worked instead, I don't know why                        setInterval(function solo() {
    jQuery('#content').find('input[type="submit"]:nth-child(3)').click();
    console.log("1");
}, 1000);

Comment: @TonyVu Why are you using `:nth-child(3)`?

Comment: I inspected the element using Google's Chrome console CSS path and was given #content > div.container-fluid > center > form > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(3) for its return.

Comment: I simplified the code abit. The actual page is here http://jsfiddle.net/5aswd0d8/2/ . I didn't think a <center> and <form>> tag would make the code not work.

Comment: Confirmed it works too. This is better though since it's more specific than saying the 3rd element of a div.

Answer (score 0):

The selector for the content div is incorrect, it should be like this

```
setInterval(function solo() {
jQuery('#content').children('submit[value="Spin again!"]').click();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried adding the hashtag but there's no discernible difference. I refresh / enter the page again and nothing happens after it loads.